# What is the correct way of fetching data from web api periodically in background even if the app is closed?

Tags: android, sockets, retrofit

I want to create an android app which should fetch data from a WEB-API after equal intervals of time (lets say after every five minutes) even if my app is closed. Also it should generate the notifications if new data is fetched.

What is the correct way to do it ??

Do I need to you background service and call a thread from on Start Command and fetch data in that thread with some sleep time ???
Fetching Data in Background..?? what is better to hit API or socket

Comment: The correct way is not to do that. Instead use a push notification from the server when data changes.

Comment: Ok but what about fetching data ??? Will background service do it ???

Comment: What research have you done? There are lots of tutorials and articles on the web that address this very subject.

Answer (score 0):

When you want your data to be fetched in background as well that generally we hit api once and then w use socket for it